# Why the slider is not working?

Tags: javascript, mootools, slideshow

My aim is to replicate the thumbnails to slide from left to right as per this page:
http://preview.vespercreative.com/citilogic/search_detail.php?pid=P2052

They key thing is I want the thumbnails to be on top. I managed to move the thumbnails on top using css but I can't get it to sroll from left to right.

**http://www.iamvishal.com/dev/sites/all/themes/andrewcustom/js/slideshow/index.html**

I am using the slideshow script from [here](http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this still an issue? The "dev" page can't be found.

Comment: Is this question still relevant?